# No option to add Credit Card Details field as a Conditional field

Tags: plugin-freeform, conditional, solspace, freeform

I'm trying to setup a payment integration having some slight issue with the conditional logic on Freeform. I'm on Craft CMS 3.8.12 (Pro Version and Freeform Pro).

The form is supposed to have a conditional field based on a user selecting a two option dropdown on whether they require a product. Then the product shows up based on user selecting 'No'.

I would like to put Credit Card details from the Special fields but this has to be based on the previous answer being 'No', and not visible in the general form without conditional logic. However, I can't see an option to add Credit Card details in the Conditionals.

[image]

Please advise if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks
Armon